# How to use natural log in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am doing a coding project. In this coding project I am constructing a calculator. I wanted to use natural log (ln). But keep getting an error that says `Anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure`. Here is my code, it is in a struct file:

```
import Foundation

struct CalculatorBrain{
    private var accumulator: Double?
    private enum Operation{
        case unaryOperation((Double) -> Double)
    }

    private var operations: Dictionary<String,Operation> =
        [
            // Unary Operations 
            "ln" : Operation.unaryOperation(log( $0 )), // this is the line where the error is
            "√" : Operation.unaryOperation(sqrt),
            "cos" : Operation.unaryOperation(cos),
            "sin" : Operation.unaryOperation(sin),
            "tan" : Operation.unaryOperation(tan),
            "sinh" : Operation.unaryOperation(sinh),
            "cosh" : Operation.unaryOperation(cosh),
            "tanh" : Operation.unaryOperation(tanh),
            "%" : Operation.unaryOperation({ $0 / 100 }),
            "±" : Operation.unaryOperation({ -$0 }),
        ]

    mutating func performOperation(_ symbol: String){
        if let operation = operations[symbol]{
            switch operation {
            case .unaryOperation (let function):
                if accumulator != nil{
                    accumulator = function(accumulator!)
                }
```

Comment: @Sulthan - Is it not pretty close to the usual calculator key legend `+/-` for change sign? (A quick search in Unicode didn't produce a `+/-`, that's not to say there isn't one...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not write `$0` because there is no closure, just specifying the name of the function is enough:

```
"ln" : Operation.unaryOperation(log)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider your code, for square root and trig functions you wrote, for example:

```
"cos" : Operation.unaryOperation(cos)
```

which just references the function, here `cos`, by name resulting in a function value. For two others you wrote a closure, for example:

```
"%" : Operation.unaryOperation({ $0 / 100 })
```

here you have use a closure (`{ ... }`) to obtain your function value. Then there is your `log` line producing an error:

```
"ln" : Operation.unaryOperation(log( $0 ))
```

this is neither the first or second case. Did you intend to write a closure, i.e. `{ log($0) }`, or just reference the existing function, i.e. `log`? Either is valid.

Pick one of the above two options, then get some sleep/coffee ;-)

HTH